# Delphi 11.1 freezing on F9 RUN, maybe other versions also affected

Tags: delphi, ide

My Delphi 11.1 installation often freezes when I press F9 to compile and run. I then have to kill one of the three LSP processes in task manager to make it work again. The process that has to be killed is always the one using the least memory.

As I did not find any hints in the web and Embarcadero support also could not help with this issue I post the astonishing solution I finally found.

Update: I added a screenshot of the layout that produces the error:
[image]

Its in German, so: (1) is project view, (2) is Structure, (3) is Palette, (4) is Messages, (5) is Events and (6) the object inspector.

With this layout in 4 of 5 cases compiling while the object inspector is visible freezes the ide.

Comment: Are you talking here about `Design Layout` or `Debug Layout` layout? By Default Delphi switches from `Design layout` to `Debug layout`. So I'm afraid the problem might be in either of those. So you should check both layouts to really track the cause of your problems. You should also provide information about your target platform. Why? When debugging Win32 applications this is done directly through Delphi debugger. But when debugging Win64 or any mobile application they are being debugged through `PAServer` which communicates with Delphi through a network connection ...

Comment: ... I experienced similar problem in Delphi 10.3 when my firewall was blocking network traffic of `PAServer`. And yes it was happening with default `Debug Layout` which was showing `Object inspector` pane while on Delphi 11.2 default `Debug layout` `Object inspector` pane is not shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason in my case and also the reason why obviously nobody else experienced that is that I created a layout where I packed all tool windows into one tabbed page on the left to make Delphi better usable on a small screen like my surface tablet.

Switching back to standard layout solved the problem. It seems to be related to putting the object inspector into tabs with other views like structure, palette and project as it only happened when the object inspector was the selected tab.

UPDATE: After some research I can confirm that the effect is caused by the object inspector being grouped with other tool windows. The problematic layout works fine if the object inspector is seperate like in this screenshot.

[image]

Perhaps this helps someone else being driven crazy by this strange effect.

I reported it towards Embarcadero: RSP-40088

Comment: Care to enrich your answer with screenshots of both the "wrong" and "correct" layouts? Preferably only that part, not whole desktops.

Comment: If you confirm you found the root cause of the issue, then please create a report at https://quality.embarcadero.com. The report should contain the steps to reproduce (In you case : arrange the desktop in a certain way). Add screen-shots showing that desktop. Creating a report will make sure that this issue will gain attention from Embarcadero and get a chance to be fixed in the next update. Thanks.

Comment: I will create a report as soon I find time. A added the screenshot, the "correct" layout is e.g. standard. I think its not a tragic error as my layout was kind of dumb, i was just used to it.

Comment: Let us know the report number once created. What is more important is the layout which cause the issue and the way to reproduce the error.

Comment: I can confirm that too. I also had packed all tool windows into one tabbed page and suffered from the same problem. I separated the object inspector tab and the problem was solved. It's a shame, because the code space has shrunk like this. +1 for your solution

Comment: Thousand thanks for finding this !  I have had this same problem for months, at least now I know how to fix it. For me this only ever happens on WIndows 11 - I have been using such a layout for years on earlier versions of Windows without no probs. EDIT: I have moved my Object Inspector to be the first/last in the group of docked windows and that also seems to help - unless I am celebrating prematurely :(

Comment: After some more fiddling I went to ObjectInspector properties  and unchecked everything except "Show read only properties" and "Bold non default values". Ever since I did this I cannot reproduce the freezing, even through I still have windows docked together in a group, specifically:  Structure, Object Inspector, Palette and Project. Fingers crossed :)

Comment: I'm also using this layout (Object inspector as a tab with other windows) and experienced frequent IDE freezes with the original Delphi 11 version. But with the current version (11.3) this problem no longer occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for finding this! I'm using the Community Edition (Currently 11.3) and was also suffering from this 'feature'.

After some experimenting I can even add some more detail. It's enough to uncheck 'Integral height (when not docked)' in 'Tools/User interface/Object inspector'. You dont have to undock the Object Inspector.

No hang-ups so far. (3 days of fairly intensive use)